# Как посчитать сумму всех чисел для каждого нуля в массиве c#

Tags: c#

Попалась задачка на собеседовании: есть нули и единицы в массиве. Надо для каждого нуля посчитать сколько единиц правее него и вывести сумму таких чисел. Сделать за один проход.

Допустим есть массив из нулей и единиц:

```
int[] z = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 };
```

Увидев 0 нужно посчитать все числа, после него и записать в переменную(или нет)
то есть 12. следующий 11, 6, 3, 2, 1. В итоге должно получиться 35. Подскажите как это сделать программно в рамках задачи.

Comment: Прошу прощения, а у Вас вообще никаких идей нет на этот счет?

Comment: а циклом можно?

Comment: `Надо для каждого нуля посчитать сколько единиц правее него` - идете от начала до первого нуля, после первого нуля - любая единица правеее какого то нуля, то есть после первого нуля считайте сумму всех единиц

Comment: @tym32167 он не понимает как это реализовать

Comment: `var result = z.SkipWhile(x=>x!=0).Sum();`

Comment: Но сам не пробывал я так вижу

Comment: @tym32167 35 не получится, некоторые единицы должны складываться несколько раз

Comment: @Igor а, понял, недочитал задачу )

Comment: Какая то больно легкая задачка для собеседования. Это на джуниора идете?

Comment: @tym32167 Вполне себе задачка на то, что человек вообще способен условие осознать и код писать. Не зря же fizzbuzz-ы придумали

Comment: @MBo "Вполне себе задачка на то, что" у человека есть пульс.

Comment: @MBo ну это же и на более сложной задаче можно проверить + ещё проверить problem solving навык и знание алгоритмов. А такая задачка как разогрев перед кодингом разве что подойдет, и то с натягом. Мне, по крайней мере, на собеседованиях давали задачи на 2-3 порядка сложнее )

Comment: Да понятно, что мнений по этому поводу может быть много, и единственно правильного не существует.

Comment: `z.Aggregate((o: 0, s: 0), (a, e) => e == 0 ? (a.o + 1, a.s) : (a.o, a.s + a.o)).s`

Answer (score 4):

Проход с начала

```
int[] z = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 };

var sum = 0;
var mult = 0;
for(var i=0; i<z.Length; i++)
{
    if (z[i] == 0) mult++;
    else sum += mult;       
}

Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Проход с конца

```
int[] z = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 };

var sum = 0;
var ones = 0;
for(var i=z.Length-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    if (z[i] == 1) ones++;
    else sum += ones;   
}

Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно написать такой метод расширения для аккумуляции:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> Accumulate<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> condition)
    {
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var x in source)
            if (condition(x)) count++;
            else yield return count;
    }
}
```

И использовать его так:

```
int[] z = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 };
foreach (var x in z.Reverse().Accumulate(x => x == 1).Reverse())
    Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Comment: Собрав все Ваши ответы воедино, можно новый `MoreLinq` написать хД

Comment: Кстати, вместо `Func<T, bool> predicate` семантически более верно, как мне кажется, использовать уже готовый делегат `Predicate<T>`, проживающий в `System`)

Comment: Ну, "Linq-однострочники" — это отдельная специальная дисциплина ruSO :)

Comment: Мною очень любимая) Порой смотришь на задачу, над которой некоторые пыхтят, выписывая десятки (а то и сотни, видел такое) строк кода, а ты уже видишь однострочное решение на `Linq` хД

Comment: `Predicate<T>` сначала и использовал, но потом заменил на `Func<T, bool>` специально, в BCL именно он используется в основном (например, в том же `Where()`), подозреваю что `Predicate<T>` более старый и всё переводят на `Func...`

Comment: Кстати, возможно. Ибо `Predicate` доступен с .Net Framework 2.0 ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать вот так, начиная проход с начала. Обозначаем в консоли ноль и считаем после него количество единиц:

```
        bool Null = false;

        int sum = 0;


        int[] array = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 };

        foreach (int x in array)
        {

            if (x == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Null");

                if (Null == false)
                    Null = true;

                else if (Null == true)
                {

                    sum = 0;

                }
            }


            if (x == 1)
            {

                if (Null == true)
                {
                    sum++;
                    Console.WriteLine(sum);
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var col = new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 };

        for (int i =0;  i < col.Length; i++)
        {

            if (col[i] == 0)
            {
                var skip = col.Skip(i).Where(x => x != 0).Sum();
                Console.WriteLine(skip);

            }

        }

        Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, каждую единицу нужно умножить на количество нулей слева и просуммировать

```
int[] z = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 };

var numberOfZeros = 0;
var sum = 0;
foreach (var number in z)
{
    if (number == 0)
        numbersOfZeros++;
    else
        sum += numberOfZeros;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        int sum = 0;
        int[] array = { 1,1,1,0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 };
        bool foundZero = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (foundZero && array[i] == 1)
            {
                sum++;
            }
            else if (array[i] == 0)
            {
                foundZero = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] mas = new int[]{1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1};
int counter = 0;
int indexcounter = 0;
for(int i = 0;i<mas.Length;i++)
{
    if (mas[i]==0 && i<mas.Length-1&&mas[i+1]==1  )
    {
       while(i<mas.Length)
        {
            if (mas[i] == 1 ) 
            { 
                counter++; 
            
            }
            i++;
            indexcounter++;
        }
        i = i - indexcounter;
        indexcounter = 0;
    }
 }
```

вроде единственное решение из всех,которое подходит под вопрос автора,но не уверен в том,что это 1 проход)